# How to tether lg optimus v without rooting

Tags: tethering

I am trying to create a wifi access point (hotspot) from my virgin mobile Optimus v to provide internet access.

It looks like there are several options if I root it but I'd rather not root it.

Bluetooth would be an acceptable alternative.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I share my wifi with my ipod or netbook](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43/how-do-i-share-my-wifi-with-my-ipod-or-netbook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a few options. The easiest seems to be :
**[QuickSettings](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bwx.bequick&hl=en)** (free, works on an unrooted Droid, including Optimus V, [reviewed here](http://www.appbrain.com/app/quick-settings/com.bwx.bequic).).  It did reveal the Wifi Hotspot setting so I could turn it on, but it didn't work. After more investigation this seems to be a limitation of Virgin Mobile (not allowing Tethering).

k

Answer (score 2):

[ClockworkMod Tether](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.koushikdutta.tether) works for sharing your phone's connection with a PC, even if your carrier blocks tethering, without root.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PDANet](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.pn.helper) to do Bluetooth tethering.